# Default value of input field causes alignment problem

Tags: html, css, svg

I am trying to build a timer and I am also trying to use SVG in particular. I have an input field that might not be sized properly but I am using alignment to deal with this problem.
However, my code seems to break if I put in a default value or even try to use javaScript to set the value once the page loads. This does not work and I am unable to type in the visible region. However, if I delete the data already in there using the delete key or if I simply don't put in a default value and type the values, the alignment seems to work just fine. Here is the code I have with the default values:

```css
body{
    background-color: black;
}
#input1, textarea{
    text-align: right;
    background-color: black;
    fill: black;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
}

#input1 ,text{
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<svg height="100vh" width="100vw">
        <circle r="25%" cx="50%" cy="50%" fill-opacity="100%" stroke="green" stroke-width="7"></circle>
            <!--TODO: add handling to button-->
        <foreignObject x="31.5%" y="42%" width="16%" height="16%" fill="black" stroke-width="0">
            <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                <label>
                    <input id ="input1" style="font-size: 450%; color: white" maxlength="2" value="05">
                </label>
            </div>
        </foreignObject>
<svg>
```

In the above code, if you remove the input, the alignment fixes itself and it stays fixed even for future updates using javaScript.

Please see the output in a full page view. Is there a reason why this happening and is there a fix I can use?

Note:The field is to the left of the center of the circle, it's just not visible because it is black.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not definitely sure, but I think the problem that's causing the alignment of the text problem in the input field is due to the value of the `width` attribute of your `foreignObject` element.

As you can see, the `font-size` of your `input` element is relatively so much bigger than the `foreignObject` can fit. That is why the text alignment is acting weird.

So basically, I could say that the value in the `input` field is not shown or wrongly aligned because of the `width` of the `foreignObject` element that is not proportional to the `font-size` of your `input` element and thus, it is somehow "hidden". Therefore, what I tried to do was mess around with the `width` attribute in the `foreignObject` element.

Original values:
`<foreignObject x="31.5%" y="42%" width="16%" height="100%" fill="black" stroke-width="0">`
[image: Originally]

After changing the `width` attribute of `foreignObject`:
`<foreignObject x="31.5%" y="42%" width="100%" height="100%" fill="black" stroke-width="0">`
[image: After]

Hope this gives you at least a little bit of idea, just in case it didn't really answer your question.